# MySQL to Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, connection-string

I used following:

- Excel 2013
- MySQL version is 5.0.67
- Windows 8 64 bit

When I connect MySQL via excel VBA (I do not need ODBC connection),I got the following error.

```
Error Description: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Error at line: 0
Error Number: -2147467259
```

I installed mysql-for-excel-1.2.1 also.
Please help me figure out the issue.

I listed code:

```
 cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.0.67 Driver};SERVER=localhost; PORT=3306;_ 
 DATABASE=Sales; USER=root; PASSWORD=sys; OPTION=3;"
```

I tried with following drivers:

- MySQL 5.0.67 Driver
- MySQL ODBC 5.0.67 Driver
- MySQL ODBC 5.0.67 ANSI Driver
- MySQL ODBC 5.0.67 Unicode Driver
- mysql-for-excel-1.2.1

Comment: 64-bit Office, or 32- bit?  More likely to work with 32-bit...

Comment: You're not breaking the string like that in the actual code, are you? VBA doesn't let you break lines in the middle of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed MySQL ODBC driver.

I estabilished connection.